# Finding a Field Isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_3[x]/(2x^3+x^2+x+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am tasked with finding a ring which is isomorphic to $R=\Bbb Z_3[x]/(2x^3+x^2+x+1)$. The question seems pretty vague, which is why I am having some trouble with it. I understand that $2x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_3[x]$, so $R$ is a field. So if I am to find a ring $S$ such that $R\cong S$, then $S$ would also be a field. I also understand that $R$ consists of quadratics (or lower degree) in $\Bbb Z_3[x]$, so it has $3^3=27$ distinct elements. The roots of the polynomial $2x^3+x^2+x+1$ are rather nasty, so I don't think that $S$ would be any field extension of $\Bbb Z_3$ involving a root of the polynomial.

**Question:** Does anyone have any hints or suggestions for fields $S$ to which $R=\Bbb Z_3[x]/(2x^3+x^2+x+1)$ is isomorphic? The only ones I can think of are of the form $\Bbb Z_3[x]/(p(x))$ where $p(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_3[x]$, but these examples seem uninteresting.

**Edit:** I usually use the First Isomorphism Theorem for these types of questions. So I am having difficulty developing a homomorphism whose kernel is $(2x^3+x^2+x+1)$.

Comment: This is indeed a weird question.  It's really easy to find a ring isomorphic to $R$: for instance, you could take $R$ itself.  Or you could take your favorite set $S$ with a bijection $f:R\to S$ and give $S$ a ring structure such that $f$ is an isomorphism...

Comment: As has been noted, there's literally only one field which this _can_ be. Can you provide the specific text of the question you're trying to answer? That might help towards giving more useful answers...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki the question literally says "Identify the following rings". So this seems even more vague, but by the lecture notes I gather that this means to find a field which the given quotient ring is isomorphic. A similar problem which I have solved is finding a field which $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ is isomorphic to. I found it is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q(\alpha )$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$.

Comment: In $R$, the element $\bar{x}$ (the congruence class of $x$) is a root of the polynomial $f$ given by $f(t) = 2t^3 + t^2 + t + 1$. $R$ is, in fact, precisely the field extension of $\mathbb{F}_3$ generated by $\bar{x}$.

Comment: Have you covered field extensions at all and adjoining roots of irreducible polynomials to fields? That would give you a different description of this ring.

Comment: @Oiler I have done field extensions like $\Bbb R(\alpha)\cong \Bbb R[x]/(x^2+1)$ where $\alpha^2+1=0$, and the one in my previous comment. However, the roots of this polynomial are very nasty, so I am not sure what field extension using a root of $2x^3+x^2+x+1$ to use.

Comment: @Dave you don't need to know a root explicitly, simply declare $\alpha$ to be such that $2\alpha^3 + \alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$ like you did with the other ones.

Comment: @Oiler I guess I am still confused because the polynomial is cubic, so it can't be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_3(\alpha)$. Would $R$ be isomorphic to something like $\Bbb Z_3(\alpha,\alpha^2):=\{a+b\alpha +c\alpha^2 : a,b,c\in\Bbb Z_3\}$ where $2\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$ (we haven't done field extensions like this before so I am not sure if this makes sense).

Comment: It would be $\mathbb{Z}_{3}(\alpha)$. You don't need to adjoin $\alpha^2$ in addition to $\alpha$ because you get $\alpha^2$ by closure of multiplication :)

Comment: @Oiler wouldn't $\Bbb Z_3(\alpha)$ only have $9$ elements though, whereas $R$ has 27, so how could they be isomorphic?

Comment: @Dave It would have 27 elements though, because you do still have $\alpha^2$. This is because $\mathbb{Z}_{3}(\alpha) = \{ a + b\alpha +c\alpha^2 \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_{3} \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid having a long string of comments, I thought I would throw in an answer. If we want a different description of $R$, let $\alpha$ be such that 
$$
2\alpha^3 + \alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 = 0 
$$ 
or equivalently 
$$ 
\alpha^3 = \alpha^2 + \alpha + 1.\\
$$
Then $\mathbb{Z}_{3}(\alpha)$ is a field (why?) and elements are of the form $a_{0} + a_{1} \alpha + a_{2} \alpha^2 + \cdots + a_{n} \alpha^n$ for $a_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}_{3}$. Now why don't we need to adjoin $\alpha^2$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ in addition to $\alpha$? Well it is redundant since its a field and $\alpha$ is an element of the field and so $\alpha^2 \in \mathbb{Z}_{3}(\alpha)$ by closure of multiplication and so $\mathbb{Z}_{3}(\alpha, \alpha^2) = \mathbb{Z}_{3}(\alpha)$.

So why is it the case that $\mathbb{Z}_{3}(\alpha) = \{ a + b \alpha + c\alpha^2 \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_{3} \}$ instead of all of those hideously long expressions like $a_{0} + a_{1} \alpha + a_{2} \alpha^2 + \cdots + a_{n} \alpha^n$? Well the relation that $\alpha^3 = \alpha^2 + \alpha + 1$ allows us to boil down powers of $\alpha$ greater than or equal to 3 to powers of $\alpha$ that are less than $3$. From here you can probably construct an obvious isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x] / \langle 2x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 \rangle $ and $\mathbb{Z}_{3}(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extesion of degree 3 of $\mathbb{Z}$, so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{3^3}$ the only field of cardinal $27$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Existence_and_uniqueness

Comment: I have a basic level of knowledge with these matters, as this is my first abstract algebra course and we just covered ideals. I am unfamiliar with the field $\Bbb F_{3^3}$.

Comment: A degree 3 extension, not extesion! (don't you use a browser having a spell check?), of $\mathbb Z_3$, right?